# Counting occurrences in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that looks like this

```
[1:[1:mammal,2:cat,3:fur],
 2:[1:mammal,2:dog,3:fur],
 3:[1:mammal,2:cat,3:fur],
 4:[1:fish,2:trout,3:scales]]
```

I wish to count the number of occurrences of animal to return an array such as this

```
[cat:2,dog:1,trout:1]
```

I have been trying unsuccessfully with a for loop, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [counting how many times an item appears in a multidimensional array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52084228/counting-how-many-times-an-item-appears-in-a-multidimensional-array-in-javascrip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct, it will be easier to return an object with key value pairs.

Here is an example using the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function:

```js
const animals = [['mammal', 'cat', 'fur'], ['mammal', 'dog', 'fur'], ['mammal', 'cat', 'fur'], ['fish', 'trout', 'scales']]

function count (animals) {
  return animals.reduce((acc, arr) => {
      for (const item of arr) {
   acc[item] = acc[item] !== undefined ? acc[item] + 1 : 1
      }

      return acc
  }, {})
}

console.log(count(animals))
```