# Count array's words (12k elements) occurrences in another multidimensional array (20k elements) in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to get this one to work, but the way I found it to work, using `regex` makes it run out of memory and/or it gives me the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: \b + +\b : Nothing to repeat.`

This is the function:

```
function countSearchTerms() {
  const filteredTerms = nGramsSht.getRange(6, 2, nGramsSht.getLastRow() - 5, 1).getValues().filter(e => e != '');
  const searchTermData = nGramFinalDataSht.getRange(1, 1, nGramFinalDataSht.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(e => e != '');

  let occurrences = [];
  for (let r = 0; r < filteredTerms.length; r++) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let a = 0; a < searchTermData.length; a++) {
      if ((new RegExp("\\b" + filteredTerms[r].toString() + "\\b").test(searchTermData[a]))) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    occurrences.push([count])
  }

  if (occurrences.length > 0) {
    nGramsSht.getRange(6, 3, nGramsSht.getLastRow() - 5, 1).clearContent();
    nGramsSht.getRange(6, 3, occurrences.length, 1).setValues(occurrences);
  }
}
```

I'd use this [answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73675223/11832197) approach, but how to count the words in `a` occurring in `b`?

```js
function wordcount() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.clearContents();
  const a = [["A"], ["earth"], ["20"], ["tunnel"], ["house"], ["earth A"], ["$100"], ["house $100"]];
  const b = [["A"], ["A Plane is expensive"], ["peaceful earth"], ["20 years"], ["tunnel"], ["tiny house"], ["earth B612"], ["$100"], ["house $100"]]
  sh.getRange(1, 1, a.length, a[0].length).setValues(a);
  let o = [... new Set(a.slice().flat().join(' ').split(' '))].map(w => [w, sh.createTextFinder(w).matchCase(true).findAll().length]);
  o.unshift(["Words","Count"]);
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 2,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Comment: btw, why `slice().flat()`? `flat` returns a new array.

Comment: You example has undefined variables please provide [mcve]

Comment: I don't understand your last comment

Comment: The answer I'm trying to use, referenced above, has the array ```b``` in which array ```a``` 's words are to be searched. The answer currently counts words in the array ```a``` itself. @Cooper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function wordcount() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.clearContents();
  const a = [["A"], ["earth"], ["20"], ["tunnel"], ["house"], ["earth A"], ["$100"], ["house $100"]];
  const b = [["A"], ["A Plane is expensive"], ["peaceful earth"], ["20 years"], ["tunnel"], ["tiny house"], ["earth B612"], ["$100"], ["house $100"]]
  sh.getRange(1, 1, b.length, b[0].length).setValues(b);
  let o = [... new Set(a.slice().flat().join(' ').split(' '))].map(w => [w, sh.createTextFinder(w).matchCase(true).findAll().length]);
  o.unshift(["Words", "Count"]);
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 2, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

| Search |  |
| --- | --- |
| A |  |
| A Plane is expensive |  |
| peaceful earth |  |
| 20 years |  |
| tunnel |  |
| tiny house |  |
| earth B612 |  |
| $100 |  |
| house $100 |  |
|  |  |
| Words | Count |
| A | 2 |
| earth | 2 |
| 20 | 1 |
| tunnel | 1 |
| house | 2 |
| $100 | 2 |

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, it timed out because of the number of elements to be processed. I don't even think Google Sheets is powerful enough for these dataset sizes.

Comment: Try running the search words in batches

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your data makes the regexp fail. You should escape it for regexp and check if not empty. I hope it helps

```
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
}

var term = escapeRegExp(filteredTerms[r].toString().trim())
if (term && (new RegExp("\\b" + term + "\\b").test(searchTermData[a]))) {
  count++;
}
```

Comment: I'll try it as soon as I'm in front of the PC. Thank you!